# Should i pre-index tables prepackaged database for room persistence library?

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, android-room

I have an sqlite database which has a (huge) table in order to be prepackaged to room. But I noticed that indexing such table before prepackaging and not indexing it and instead relying on room indexing queries (specified by annotations) seem to same in terms of performance since they both take the same amount of time for initial loading. atleast this is what I've noticed.

Are both methods the same or is one faster than the other in terms of initial loading (due to indexing)?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes, i noticed that pre-indexing is faster after several trials

Comment: As I said in my answer :) If you think that my answer helped you, mark is as accepted, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get performance for sql statements executing right after db will be copied you can index all tables before packaging DB because room [just copy a file from your directory](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:room/room-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java;drc=3aa5751b1de8b1de34576075b74e73e167b055a6;l=188) therefore the room copies indexes too which contains in db file. But indexes take a disk place and if you have many data with many indexes the copy process can took more time to copy you pre-packaged db and may be creating indexes in run time(when sqlite executes statements) can be better in terms of user experience . I think in most cases will be better if you will pre-index tables in pre-packaged DB.

Comment: Suprisingly, i didn't see this answer. This perfectly answers my question

Comment: I should be the one to thank you for your answer, sir!

Answer (score 0):

If the database is huge... don't pre-package, but synchronize during the onboarding.
One still can provide a basic database, in order to ensure the most basic functionality.